# Binding multiple Dropdowns and textfields

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox

In my project I have 2 dropdowns 1 listbox and 1 textbox. I Have already bound the 2 dropdowns together "PostalDropDown" and "CityDropDown" from the database and it works fine, Then i bind the listbox also to the previous dropdowns and it works fine also!

My question here i still have the last Textbox which i want it to display the name which is also bound to the results of dropdowns.
I cannot figur it out because the textbox does not have the SelectValue property, so I cannot assign it like i did with my dropdowns or listbox like i did:

```
       if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string, string>> data = GetData();
            DropDownListPostal.DataSource = data.Select(tuple => tuple.Item1).Distinct().ToList();

            DropDownListPostal.DataBind();
            DropDownListCity.DataValueField = "Item1";

            DropDownListCity.DataTextField = "Item2";
            DropDownListCity.DataSource = data;
            DropDownListCity.DataBind();

            ListBox1.DataValueField = "item1";
            ListBox1.DataTextField = "Item4";
            ListBox1.DataSource = data;
            ListBox1.DataBind();

        }              
    }
```

and then i view the result on this on the selectedindexchanged on first dropdown:

```
     protected void DropDownListPostal_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //DropDownListPostal.ClearSelection();

        ListBox1.ClearSelection();
        DropDownListCity.ClearSelection();           
        var postal = DropDownListPostal.SelectedValue;
        var listItem = DropDownListCity.Items.FindByValue(postal);
        var street = ListBox1.Items.FindByValue(postal);


        listItem.Selected = true;            
        street.Selected = true;
```

Can anyone show me how to add the rest of the database results on a textbox? 
I can put the whole code for the page if you all want.

Cheers

Comment: Edit your question to exactly what you are unable to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to show all of the items in a Textbox which is quite strange you can display them comma seperated like this

```
TextBoxId.Text = String.Join(",", data.Select(op => op.Name));
```

Where Name is the property that contains the property you want to display in textbox

**Edit**

If you want to display the selected items of Listbox then loop on its item and check if the item is selected then display it in your textbox.

```
foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    txtval.Text += " " + item.Text +"/"+ dropdowncity.SelectedItem.Text +"/"+ dropdownpostal.SelectedItem.Text;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi Fraz, Actully no i just realized i have been doing it worng, I only want to retrive the result of street name connected to the postal/city.
Thats why i put the results in a listbox because the City can have more then one street resotred

Comment: I want the textbox to be updated with a name everytime i click a postal in the dropdown

Comment: Hi fraz, the textbox is showing something now, but its not the items of listbox i want to display. i want to display the names the is conncted to the listbox/dropdowncity/dropdownpostal from the database

Comment: I have updated text property now it will concatenate all three control selected value

Comment: Haha I must be really bad at explaining. Im so sorry. I try again
My item in the listbox is a "Street Name" the Street Name has an "Owner Name". It's the ownername i want to display. Basically i want filter my textbox so it display the name of the owner who is connected to the street name which is also conncted to the city and postal.

Comment: your first aproach was fine, but its displays all the names of persons who is in the current postal/city:
 NavnBox.Text = String.Join(",", data.Select(op => op.Item3)); 

But i only want to show when "row" at a time